# Too easy to lose custom flag message

Tags: feature-request

Here's the scenario...

1. Click the "flag" link on a  question
2. Select "in need of moderator intervention"
3. Type your message
4. Instead of clicking the "Flag Question" button, accidentally overshoot and click outside the popup
5. Your message is lost

It would be nice if the UI would retain the message text so that you don't actually lose it. (And/or don't lose the text in the first place - maybe a confirmation before closing the popup).

[image]

Comment: Same for custom close reasons, it would be nice to have this improved.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. What if I change my mind? Do Iu then need to remove the message when I want to flag another post for another reason? How do I know it's saved my removal of the previous text, so that it's empty next time I open it? :) Confirmation would also be a little annoying, and result in me having to just double click to get out the dialog.

Comment: Remembering it for that specific post using a javascript variable (so refresh clears it) or short-lived cookie would be my preference. You rarely change your mind and want to flag exactly the same post for moderator attention but for an entirely different reason, and removing a piece of text is a lot easier than writing the same piece of text again after accidentally deleting it.

Comment: Another option would be: don't close the popup IF there is text in the messagebox, unless the user clicks Cancel. Clicking outside the popup could do nothing in that case.

Comment: Never trust anything to a web interface (unless you don't mind losing it). Prepare it offline in a text document. One of the worst of all time is [LBRY](https://lbry.com/)'s web interface - even editing comments can make them disappear!

Comment: Related: [Bounty modal window progress is lost when clicking “share” on an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354904/289905).

Comment: It could keep the text until you refresh the page, @Scratte. That seems like a nice compromise.